# Is it possible to deploy or extract a power view report from Excel to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013, business-intelligence, excel-2013, powerview

I created some very nifty Power View reports in excel, however I would like to view the reports from sharepoint without opening excel first (as if the power view was created entirely from sharepoint without Excel).

The most valable solution I could think of was to start over with new reports in Sharepoint and recreate the whole thing in browser. I do hope there is a better way to achieve this.

Is there a solution to extract the power view reports and publish them to Sharepoint? Any help is appreciated!

If it matters, I am site administrator for the sharepoint environment.
This is the result I would like to have:

[image: Screenshot of power view document]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the bi demo script at https://www.microsoftofficedemos.com/

To publish the Power View Report to SharePoint.

1. In Excel, on the File tab, click Save As.
2. In the Save As window, under Places, click SharePoint, and then click Browse.
3. In the Save As dialog, click Browser View Options.
4. In Browser View Options, click Sheets in drop down.
5. In list of sheets, click the sheet that contains your Power View report, and then click OK.
6. In Save As dialog, navigate to the Reports Gallery, if not selected by default.
7. Click Save to upload the workbook from Excel to SharePoint report gallery.

EDIT: Unfortunately you can't extract the power view per this info, office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/…. There's a [suggestion on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/779456/publish-or-save-rdlx-from-xlsx-files) that you can vote on to add this feature in future versions

Comment: This is a bit closer than I was, however the power view is still in the excel file. I would like to take the power view out of the excel file and use is as rdlx file (so I don't need excel anymore to open it). I updated my question with a screenshot.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Unfortunately you can't do that per this info, http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/power-view-explore-visualize-and-present-your-data-HA102835634.aspx. There's a suggestion on Connect that you can vote on to add this feature in future versions, http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/779456/publish-or-save-rdlx-from-xlsx-files.